# Do parentheses force evaluation-order in (current) C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, parentheses, operator-precedence

I'm hoping someone can cite chapter and verse from a recent C standard; I assume that it's there and I've just been unable to find it.

In the old days, the C language definition specifically allowed the compiler to evaluate associatively equivalent expressions, *even in the presence of parentheses*.  Thus, the source statement

```
a = (b + c) + d;
```

might actually be evaluated by adding c and d, and then adding b to that result. (see: K&R, 1st edition, section 2.12, p.49).  This wording was removed in the 2nd edition, but it does *not* specifically say that the expression *must* be evaluated as parenthesized.  My understanding is that this was part of the reason for introducing the "unary +" hack: in the statment "a = +(b + c) + d;" the unary plus would force the evaluation of (b+c).  Alternatively, one could rely on the definition of a sequence-point, and use multiple statements:

```
tmp = b + c;
a = tmp + d;
```

and hope that an overly aggressive optimizing compiler doing forward-substitution would not screw things up.

I have heard it claimed that this sort if thing is no longer true in the current C standard(s), and that parentheses are respected during sub-expression evaluation.  I have not managed to find an explicit statement to this effect in the language of the actual standard.  In particular, the standard does *not* say something like that there is a sequence point after a parenthesized sub-expression (something that would probably be an overly-restrictive bad idea, but would clearly define the evaluation).

Comment: I would be very surprised if this has changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "screw things up"? If there's no overflow, there's no difference between `(b + c) + d` and `b + (c + d)`. And if there's overflow, you have undefined behavior either way.

Comment: All this is governed by the "as if" rule -- the compiler can generate any code that produces the same result as the specification describes.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you believe that the "as if" rule does allow for the evaluation of *mathematically* equivalent expressions, even in the presence of parentheses?  That's certainly the way it was in the old days; you believe this hasn't changed ?

Comment: As far as "screw things up" goes, the canonical example is in Kahan's summation algorithm, which includes lines like "t = sum + y;  c = (t - sum) - y;".  Forward substitution would yield "c = 0.0" which is exactly not what you want.

Comment: They can't change it.  It's too widely accepted.

Comment: @bron Had to look up Kahan algorithm. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm#Possible_invalidation_by_compiler_optimization) mentions **ANSI C standard prohibited re-ordering in order to make C better suited for numerical applications**

Comment: I think that's talking about optimization across separate statements, not parentheses within a single expression. Parentheses are just for overriding default operator precedence, not specifying order of operations.

Comment: What types are `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`? If there are unsigned integer, the order is irrelevant, if there are signed integer and don't generate a overflow, the order is irrelevant, if they do, then you have UB in any case. Are they volatile integers or floats?

Answer (score 3):

The relevant section of the standard is C11 [5.1.2.3 "Program execution"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3).

To summarise, C is defined in terms of an abstract machine which produces *observable behaviour*, whose definition can be seen in point 6 of that section. (Basically, output). The compiler can do whatever it likes to a conforming program, so long as the observable behaviour generated matches the observable behaviour that the abstract machine would produce for executing the program in accordance with the language specification.

In your example, adding a unary `+` makes no difference to the observable behaviour so the compiler can ignore it.

In this specific example the compiler can re-order the addition because it knows that doing addition of multiple `int` operands produces the same result regardless of ordering   (where "causes undefined behaviour" counts as the same result if the main ordering does it).

Comment: See also C11 [§6.5 Expressions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5) where some of the rules of expression evaluation order are laid out (before delving into the details of specific operators).

Comment: For ints maybe so, but I never said anything about ints.  This sort of stuff can matter for floats, e.g. Kahan's summation algorithm.  And while unary+ makes no difference to the meaning of the expression in a mathematical sense, my understanding was that part of the original justification for the unary+ hack was that its semantic was specifically defined to force the evaluation.

Comment: Quite so, @bron.  And where order of evaluation *can* make a difference, conforming C implementations are required to respect the parentheses in that regard.

Comment: I would very much like to believe that is true.  In the old days it specifically was *not* true, and I have not managed to find chapter and verse in the current standard that says this behaviour has changed, and that the more sensible interpretation is required in order to be standard conforming.

Comment: @bron the same rationale applies to any situation.  If `(a+b)+c` and `a+(b+c)` would give exactly the same result then the compiler can do either. If they would give different results the compiler has to do the first one. For floating point there is some leeway specific to floating point operations that's beyond the scope of this answer,  if you meant to ask specifically about floating point operation reordering then you should focus your question on that (ask a new question or search this site as I'm sure it already has been covered)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer points out that C implementations are permitted a great deal of latitude with respect to execution details, provided that the program's *observable behavior* matches that defined for the abstract machine.  Although that is both true and relevant, it is at risk of giving a false impression.

In many cases, a C implementation cannot fully determine at compilation time what deviations from abstract machine behavior can be accommodated without changing the observable behavior.  There are multiple reasons for this, among them

- programs being spread across multiple translation units
- program dependence on values determined only at runtime
- objects being accessible via pointers / possible pointer aliasing
- long / complex dependency chains

Therefore, one should not interpret implementation freedom -- whose formal definition serves primarily to allow implementations to optimize -- as blanket license to reorder evaluation willy nilly.  In practice, modern C implementations are very reliable about avoiding optimizations that can change observable behavior, at least by default.  Inasmuch as modern CPUs can and do perform out or order execution at their own discretion, that turns out to be pretty good for having any conforming implementations at all.

Supposing that implementations indeed conform, then, the question should not be whether expression evaluation actually *is* reordered, but rather whether C permits it to *appear* to be reordered.  That is, it is the requirements of abstract machine behavior that seem most relevant to me.  For this, the most relevant part of the standard is [section 6.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5).

In particular:

> The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced
>   before the value computation of the result of the operator.

and

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.

Given your example expression

> ```
> a = (b + c) + d;
> ```

, then, that specifies that the subexpressions `(b + c)` and `d` are evaluated first, and then their sum is computed.  Earlier versions of the standard had similar wording, especially to the latter part, and I think it uncontroversial that the abstract machine behavior defined by every version of the standard requires the same.

If you can't tell the difference (up to the limit of observable behavior) then do you actually care what reordering is performed?  There reasons why you might do -- execution time, for example, is the biggest one -- but you should not worry overmuch about correctness.

Answer (score 0):

A C implementation is required to produce the result expressed in the source code. It may produce this result using any computations it chooses. For this purpose the results of a program are what the C standard defines as *observable behavior*:

- Data written into files.
- Input and output dynamics of interactive devices.
- Accesses to volatile objects.

If the source code evaluates `(a+b)+c` and prints it (so that the result is observable behavior), the C implementation must produce a result that is the same as adding `a` and `b` and then adding `c`, but it is not required to obtain that result by adding `a` and `b` and then adding `c`.

However, the C standard permits floating-point expressions to be evaluated with more precision and exponent range than their nominal types (for example, `double` arithmetic could be used for expressions containing only `float` operands), and it does not specify the accuracy required for floating-point arithmetic and library routines. If you are concerned about the precise behavior of floating-point expressions, then you must consider more than just order of evaluation; you must consider the quality and properties of the C implementation you use.

Additional, some “C” compilers do not adhere to the C standard with regarding to floating-point behavior. Again, you must consider the quality and properties of the C implementation you use.

The C standard requires a cast or assignment to “remove” the excess precision. So, if you write:

```
t = a+b;
printf("%.99g\n", t+c);
```

then the compiler must produce the result as if `(a+b)+c` had been evaluated to some precision and then rounded to its nominal type, and then `c` had been added. This can produce double-rounding errors, as the computation of `a+b` with excess precision can round in such a way that the subsequent rounding to the nominal type produces a different result from adding `a+b` solely in the nominal type.

In summary, if you want precise control of floating-point arithmetic, you cannot rely on the C standard. You must seek assurances from your specific compiler (such as compiler switches to use only the nominal type) or use another programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied.  I would have expected the standard to be a bit more explicit about this point, but I guess not.  I'll summarize what I've gleaned from this discussion, using my canonical example of the Kahan summation algorithm as a concrete instance:

Consider the following (err, item, and totalSum are type "double"):

```
err = ((nextItem + totalSum) - totalSum) - nextItem;
```

Here, we are in a loop, summing up the elements of an array of items.
IF the above statement is in fact executed exactly as written, "err"
will contain the bits that would otherwise "fall off the end" due
to limited precision (totalSum is large compared to nextItem).

The C abstract machine requires that an expression be evaluated
"as-if" it was computed as written.  C generally permits an intermediate
expression to be evaluated at a higher precision, and then the final
result rounded to fit.  Unfortunately, the C abstract machine
has infinite precision.  This means it *is* legal/conformant for an
implementation to optimize the above expression into:

```
err = 0.0;
```

since, if you had infinite precision, they would be the same.

A particular implementation *may* choose to implement stricter rules
about expression evaluation (and, admittedly, all real implementations
do), for example to conform to IEEE 754 semantics, but this is not
*required* by the C standard.

HOWEVER, the standard *does* require that when there is an assignment
or a cast, the value in question must be converted to the correct
type at that point.  In practice this breaks the infinite-precision
paradigm.  So if we write the expression like so:

```
double tmp = nextItem + totalSum;
tmp = tmp - totalSum;
err = tmp - nextItem;
```

Here, the standard guarentees that we *do* get the effect we want,
since when we assign the sub-expression to tmp, the value must be
rounded to fit, and so forward substitution is not allowed to cancel
out the terms.  We could even do this as:

```
err = ((double)((double)(nextItem + totalSum)) - totalSum) - nextItem;
```

which looks pretty weird, since all the variables are already double,
but the cast forces the compiler to consider the effect of limited
precision during optimization.

Whether or not a particular implementation actually really is
standard conforming regarding this point is a different question.